# sed: replace pattern only if followed by empty line

Tags: sed

I need to replace a pattern in a file, only if it is followed by an empty line. Suppose I have following file:

```
test
test

test

...
```

the following command would replace all occurrences of `test` with `xxx`

```
cat file | sed 's/test/xxx/g'
```

but I need to only replace `test` if next line is empty. I have tried matching a `hex code`, but that doesn ot work:

```
cat file | sed 's/test\x0a/xxx/g'
```

The desired output should look like this:

```
test
xxx

xxx

...
```

Comment: All lines end with a "newline". Do you intend to change only those that are followed by a *blank line*? Perhaps you could show the desired output for your given input.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill - thanks for the correction. I have edited my question

Comment: Thanks, much clearer now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '$!N;s/test(\n\s*)$/xxx\1/;P;D' file
```

Keep a window of 2 lines throughout the length of the file and if the second line is empty and the first line contains the pattern then make a substitution.

Answer (score 3):

Suggested solutions for `sed`, `perl` and `awk`:

**sed**

```
sed -rn '1h;1!H;${g;s/test([^\n]*\n\n)/xxx\1/g;p;}' file
```

I got the idea from [sed multiline search and replace](http://austinmatzko.com/2008/04/26/sed-multi-line-search-and-replace/). Basically slurp the entire file into sed's hold space and do global replacement on the whole chunk at once.

**perl**

```
$ perl -00 -pe 's/test(?=[^\n]*\n\n)$/xxx/m' file
```

`-00` triggers *paragraph mode* which makes perl read chunks separated by one or several empty lines (just what OP is looking for). Positive look ahead `(?=)` to anchor substitution to the last line of the chunk.

*Caveat:* `-00` will squash multiple empty lines into single empty lines.

**awk**

```
$ awk 'NR==1 {l=$0; next}
       /^$/ {gsub(/test/,"xxx", l)}
       {print l; l=$0}
       END {print l}' file
```

Basically store previous line in `l`, substitute pattern in `l` if current line is empty. Print `l`. Finally print the very last line.

**Output in all three cases**

```
test
xxx

xxx

...
```

Answer (score 2):

Using sed

```
sed -r ':a;$!{N;ba};s/test([^\n]*\n(\n|$))/xxx\1/g'
```

explanation

```
:a                    # set label a
$ !{                  # if not end of file
    N                 # Add a newline to the pattern space, then append the next line of input to the pattern space
    b a               # Unconditionally branch to label. The label may be omitted, in which case the next cycle is started. 
}
#  simply, above  command :a;$!{N;ba} is used to read the whole file into pattern.
s/test([^\n]*\n(\n|$))/xxx\1/g   # replace the key word if next line is empty (\n\n) or end of line ($)
```