# Append to non-empty line that doesn't start with whitespace AND is followed, two lines down, by a non-empty line that doesn't start with whitespace

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I am converting several unruly, early 90's DOS-generated text files to something more usable.  I need to append a set of characters to all of the non-empty lines in said text files that don't start with whitespace AND that are followed, *two lines down*, by another non-empty line that doesn't start with whitespace (I will refer to all single lines of text that meet these characteristics as "target" lines).  BTW, irrelevant to the problem are the characteristics of the line *directly* below each of the target lines.

Of interest is the fact that all of the target lines in the above-mentioned text files end with the same character.  Also, the command I'm looking for needs to slot into a rather long pipeline.

Suppose I have the following file:

```
foo

third line foo

fifth line foo
 this line starts with a space foo
 this line starts with a space foo

ninth line foo

eleventh line foo

 this line starts with a space foo

last line foo
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
foobar

third line foobar

fifth line foo
 this line starts with a space foo
 this line starts with a space foo

ninth line foobar

eleventh line foo

 this line starts with a space foo

last line foo
```

Although I'm looking for a sed solution, awk and perl are welcome as well.  All solutions must be able to be used in a pipeline.  Also welcomed are solutions which handle a more general case (e.g. able to append the desired text to target lines that end in various ways, including whitespace).

Now, for the backstory:

I recently asked a question similar to the subject question a few days ago (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35966938/append-to-line-that-is-preceded-and-followed-by-empty-line)).  As you can see, I got some great answers.  It turned out, however, that I did not fully understand my problem, so I did not ask the correct question that would actually solve said problem.

Now, I'm asking the right question!

Based on what I learned by scrutinizing the answers to the question I linked to above, I've cobbled together the following sed command

```
sed '1N;N;/^[^[:space:]]/s/^\([^[:space:]].*\o\)\(\n\n[^[:space:]].*\)$/\1bar\2/;P;D' infile
```

Ugly, yes, but it works for my humble purposes.  Indeed, as my original intent with this question was to post a question, then self-answer same, you can see this `sed` construct posted below as one of the answers (posted by me).

I'm sure there are better ways to solve this particular problem, however...any ideas, anyone?

Comment: Question was stated incorrectly when initially posted.  Now fixed.  Sorry to anyone who was inconvenienced.

Comment: After seeing that my question had been put on hold, I endeavored to edit same, in the hopes if making it more clear.  How did I do?

Comment: Add a colon after `http` in your link.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Oops!  Fixed!

Comment: Uh oh!  My question has been in purgatory for three days and is about to be banished to the fires of hell - what to do?  I re-edited said question and, at this point, don't know exactly what is still wrong with it!  Help!

Comment: "Write some code for me" is generally a good way to get shut down. Try something yourself and ask something of the form "I did this and it broke here, please help".

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for your insight.  Yes, I am aware of that, and it was my intention to show effort by linking to another one of my questions (see the "back story" section of the original question.  Also, it was also my original intent to ask a question, then answer it myself (see below).  I guess I did not do all of this in a clear enough fashion.

Comment: Question re-written, and effort to solve same validated as of yesterday.  Please remove from hold.

Comment: This question was banished, closed.  All important information has been added to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35966938/append-to-line-that-is-preceded-and-followed-by-empty-line), as my intent was to preserve the code used to solve the problem.  Perhaps someone else will find it useful...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This sed one-liner seems to do the trick for the specific case outlined in the OP:

```
sed '1N;N;/^[^[:space:]]/s/^\([^[:space:]].*\o\)\(\n\n[^[:space:]].*\)$/\1bar\2/;P;D' infile
```

Thanks to the excellent clarifying information given by [Benjamin W.](http:////https://stackoverflow.com/users/3266847/benjamin-w) in his answer to [one of my recent questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35966938/append-to-line-that-is-preceded-and-followed-by-empty-line), I was able to cobble together this one-liner that solved my specific problem.  Please refer to same if you wish to gain insight into said command.

Comment: That's a ridiculous mis-use of sed. Most of those language constructs have been obsolete for 40 years and/or aren't supported by all seds. sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything else you should be using awk for simplicity, clarity, portability, performance, and almost every other desirable quality of software.

Comment: This one-liner gives me the desired output, not only for the test case shown in the OP, but when used with my actual text files (mentioned in the OP).

Comment: A script that produces the expected output given some input set is the starting point for identifying a solution, not the end point. Imagine yourself modifying that script to do just about anything else (e.g. add bar1, bar2, bar3, etc. instead of just bar each time) - could you? Now port it to, say, Solaris where it won't work as written - could you modify it to work there? Why would you bother when an awk script is simpler, clearer, easier to enhance, more portable, and better in [almost] every other way. You're using a bunch of sed constructs that were only relevant before awk was invented.

Comment: @Ed Morton If someone were to submit a solution that utilizes `awk`, I'd be grateful...

Comment: I [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36075198/1745001) I posted a solution when you asked the question. You might want to ask a new question if neither that nor your own accepted answer do what you want.

Comment: @ Ed Morton Oops! Missed that! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From your posted expected output it looks like you meant to say "is followed, two lines down, by a line that **DOES NOT** start with whitespace" instead of "is followed, two lines down, by a line that *DOES* start with whitespace".

This produces the output you show:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR>2 { print p2 ((p2 ~ /^[^[:blank:]]/) && /^[^[:blank:]]/ ? "bar" : "") }
{ p2=p1; p1=$0 }
END { print p2 ORS p1 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
foobar

third line foobar

fifth line foo
 this line starts with a space foo
 this line starts with a space foo

ninth line foobar

eleventh line foo

 this line starts with a space foo

last line foo
```

It simply keeps a 2 line buffer and adds "bar" to the end of the line being printed given whatever condition you need. It will work on all POSIX awks and any others that support POSIX character classes (for the rest, change `[[:blank:]]` to `[ \t]`).

Comment: Ed, you are correct in that I mis-stated the objective.  Can't believe I missed that!  The question in the OP has been duly corrected...

Comment: @Digger You are the OP, not the post.

Comment: @MadPhysicist OK, thanks.  Different colloquialisms in use here than those used in my five motorcycle mechanics forums....

Answer (score 1):

You have over-analysed the problem so that your question now reads as a computer program, and you have got that program wrong. Requirements are best explained using examples and real data, so that we have some hope of rationalising the problem in our heads

This Perl program alters your algorithm so the output matches your required output

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

chomp(my @data = <>);

my $i = 0;
for ( @data ) {
    $_ .= 'bar' if /^\S/ and $data[$i+2] =~ /^\S/;
    ++$i;
    last if $i+2 > $#data;
}

print "$_\n" for @data;
```

#### output

```
foobar

third line foobar

fifth line foo
 this line starts with a space foo
 this line starts with a space foo

ninth line foobar

eleventh line foo

 this line starts with a space foo

last line foo
```

Comment: Borodin is correct, the question, as originally posed, was not correct.  The question in the OP has been corrected since the subject answer was posted.